# c# IndexOutOfRangeException boolean char array

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, char

Firs of all, sorry for my English. 
i`m working on a console program and theres a error that is located in a "if" method. i let you the core of the program so you can run it and help me with this problem

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String read = "auto";
        String write;

        char[] read_arr = read.ToCharArray();


        Console.WriteLine("Escribe la siguiente palabra: {0}", read);

        write = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] write_arr = write.ToCharArray();


        if (read_arr.Length == write_arr.Length)
        {
            if(read == write)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Felicitaciones!!, Acertaste");

            }
            else
            {
                for(int c = 0; c <= read_arr.Length; c++)
                {
                    if (read_arr[c] != write_arr[c])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("La letra '{0}' es incorrecta", write_arr[c]);
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Lo siento, te has equivocado");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lo siento, te has equivocado");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not how you do it.  Here is how you do it: you write *preciesely* what the input that you gave it is, and you write *precisely* what the error that you got is, and *precisely* on which line you got it, in the question.

Comment: You have `read_arr` and `write_arr`, if they are not the same length then your code will not be able to access (index) an item at index `c` so you will get an error.

Comment: If you have an array named `names` with 2 items and you write `var name = names[8]` or any index except 0 and 1, you will get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int c = 0; c <= read_arr.Length; c++)
```

You start for 0, and iterates until Length. You should use strict comparison. Remove the "=" char from `c <= read_arr.Length`:

```
for(int c = 0; c < read_arr.Length; c++)
```

a 3 size starts array index is 0 - 1 - 2. The 3 is not included as you started by 0.

Comment: Your answer will solve the problem but you may want to make it very clear that you removed the `=` so the OP understands the change.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Sometimes little changes are hard to notice, that's a good remark.